# To put more "weight/power" into a conclusion

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, writing

I am trying to find an expression which would meet my needs. In the report that I am currently writing I would like to explain that I have done a certain action in order to "put more weight/power" into a conclusion.

There is an expression for this purpose in the French language (*mettre du poids dans*), and I know that translating an expression from a language to another nearly never works. I tried to find the solution by asking Google but I guess I am not using the correct keywords... Does anyone would have any ideas?

[EDIT]

I am actually trying to say that my action will *carry more weight* (thanks [Rant](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15284/rant)) but I do not know how I should formulate it. I have started my sentence like this:

The investigation will also draw a timeline of activities in order to add **expression** to the previous arguments.

I have moved from **conclusion** to **argument** as it make more sense in the current context. How can I add an expression which means *carry more weight*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to use words that come attached with a sense of reliability and foundation.  Without some additional context, it will be hard to find the exact phrase you're looking for.

The equivalent phrase in English is, as a matter of fact, *to carry weight*

Your best bet will be to use the correct form of it.  It's typically used to mean *influential* so I hope that helps

EDIT:  There are a couple options here...from the sounds of things, this might be acceptable:

*The investigation will also draw a timeline of activities in order to add **momentum** to the previous arguments.*

You could also swap out *momentum* for **weight, credibility, solidarity** or you could even say *in order to help the previous arguments **carry more weight***.

Any of those I think will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've put more context in my question.

Comment: +1 credibility. Also justification, emphasis. Or to support, reinforce the argument.

Comment: I really don't think you can *add momentum to an argument*.

Comment: *Momentum* does sound a little strange in this context upon review.  I was thinking of it alongside the words like *draw a timeline*.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do something to add weight to an **argument** in English. It would seem a little odd to add weight to a **conclusion** in any language because a conclusion can’t do any more than, well, conclude. It’s difficult to advise further without knowing the broader context.

Comment: I agree it is difficult to advise without further contextual knowledge, but weight can be added to conclusions as well as arguments.

Comment: Agreed it sounds odd to *add weight to a conclusion*. I think the normal phrasing would be *add weight to a concluding argument*.

Comment: ...but I could certainly say something [reinforces my conclusion](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reinforces+my+conclusion&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 0):

A proper word for the job is *[substantiate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substantiate)*, "1. to verify something by supplying evidence; to corroborate or authenticate. 2. to give material form or substance to something; to embody."

For example: "To substantiate previous arguments, the investigation will include a timeline of activities."

Relevant synonyms of *substantiate* include
*corroborate, demonstrate, establish, strengthen, support, sustain, validate*.  *[Corroborate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corroborate)*, for instance, means "To confirm, strengthen or support something with additional evidence; to attest or vouch."

Comment: Thanks for the input! I think the synonyms are better for me. I do not remember reading any technical papers with _substantiate_ in it. Moreover, as my English is quite poor, it would look out of place in my report :)